# android, how to add ListView items from XML?

Tags: android, listview

I have an XML ( absolutelayout ) template, of how I want my ListView items to look like.

What would be the best way to add this items to my ListView?

On, and one more thing, how do I change ListView's height from java?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Inflate the layout with the items in the getView, but why? Changing listview height or any other descriptives can be achieved with modifying Layout.Params.

Comment: >>> Inflate the layout with the items in the getView, but why?
Why? Hmm... is there a better way to fill that ListView?

Comment: Yes. Create <Listview > <your items > </listview> you have your listview items in your xml, all you have to do is to fill with data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an list view adapter like this, (Sample for a contact list)

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>
{

    private int resource;

    public ContactListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Contact> items)
    {
        super(context, resource, items);

        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LinearLayout contactListView;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            contactListView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
            layoutInflater.inflate(resource, contactListView, true);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.textViewName = (TextView) contactListView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.textViewAddress = (TextView) contactListView.findViewById(R.id.address);

            contactListView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            contactListView= (LinearLayout) convertView;

            holder = (ViewHolder) contactListView.getTag();
        }

        Contact item = getItem(position);

        holder.textViewName.setText(item.getName());
        holder.textViewAddress.setText(item.getAddress());

        return contactListView;
    }

    protected static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView textViewName;
        TextView textViewAddress;
    }
}
```

Set this adapter to your listview. Pass in the resource id of your xml layout to this adapter. It would deflate the view from the xml and add it to the listview.

You can also adjust the heights of the listview items in the above **getView()** method of the adapter. Using **LayoutParams** ofcourse.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip" android:focusable="false" android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/empty" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Loading" android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I mean to add your item VIEWS. Then fill your items with data.

Changing listview height or any other descriptives can be achieved with modifying `Layout.Params`