# Parse JSON file and display an ImageButton and TextView for each entry

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have a JSON file that I want to parse. For each entry in the JSON file, I want to display an ImageButton (this will be an icon) and a TextView (a title). I'm just wondering what the best way of doing this is..

I DO NOT want to make a listview.. it is more of a grid view. I want 2-3 icons per row (so 2-3 columns) kind of like apple's bookshelf

I've started off with..

```
json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromSDCard("/sdcard link to the file") //this gets the json file
JSONArray entries = json.getJSONArray("entries");
ArrayList<String> alTitle = new ArrayList<String>();

 for(int i=0;i<entries.length();i++){

    JSONObject e = entries.getJSONObject(i);
   ..//create arraylist to store entries?
   //alTitle.add(e.getString("title"));
}
//create ImageButton and TextView?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a listview inside this activity or a ListActivity.  Then use a list adapter to create a layout for each list item.

There are samples supplied in the SDK for this to get you started.  You will find these in the android-sdk folder wherever you have installed this on your PC.

There are also many tutorials on the internet so I cannont list them all, but here are a few to get you started.  These are the top google searches.

[Android Series: Custom ListView items and adapters](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)

[Android: Dealing with ListActivities, customized ListAdapters and custom-designed items](http://united-coders.com/phillip-steffensen/android-dealing-with-listactivities-customized-listadapters-and-custom-designed-0)

**UPDATE**

Sorry I missed the specification of using a GridView.  The [officaial GridView documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) includes a full sample  The same idea applies using an adapter you can compare the different type of view in the [Hello Views section of the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html)

Here is a full example, you will need to add any additional controll into your adapter.  Again, there are samples in the sdk itself and these are invaluable to Android developers.

Comment: i don't want a listview. I want more of a grid view e.g 2-3 icons per row. I've seen the listview and have used one for another project.

Comment: Please see my ammended answer.  I don't know how I missed the specification of a grid, did you edit the question?

Comment: Ye I mentioned in another comment about having to update my question because I kept getting listview  replies. Thanks for the docs - it will help!

Comment: Editing questions that change the question itself is generally frowned upon so be careful. Usual way is to put the word **EDIT** in bold followed by additional information at the foot of your current question rather than in the middle.  Also you should up vote **and** accept answers.  Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into the GSON library for Android. It's supposedly a lot faster and easier to use than org.json in the stock SDK. I've also ran into bugs with the stock json library.

Basically it adds an interface similar to Java's serializables.

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

User Guide: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the JSON, create an ArrayList then pass that ArrayList to an ArrayAdapter.

Use a custom implementation of ArrayAdapter as mentioned here
[android, how to add ListView items from XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766224/android-how-to-add-listview-items-from-xml)

Create a layout XML with an icon and a TextView and deflate it in the getView method of your ArraAdapter implementation. Populate the values and you are done.

Comment: I should edit my post. I do applogise but I do not want a list view. A list view is one column with 1 row/cell taking the whole width.. What i want to do is more of a grid view and have about 2-3 icons per row (so about 2-3 columns)